# Do WriteProcessMemory and similiar functions invalidate the possibly cached data?

Tags: c++, c, ipc

I have an existing program which I need to communicate with over IPC. I can modify small parts of it but can't add any fancy solutions like shared memory, pipes or sockets. So I'd like to communicate with functions that directly read / write into the programs address space:

- `process_vm_writev` on linux
- `WriteProcessMemory` on windows
- `mach_vm_write` on macOS

If I modify a value in memory with one of these functions is the possibly cached copy of the old value invalidated? If not is a volatile pointer enough to instantly retrieve the new value?

Comment: I have no experience of using these, but for re-entrancy reasons you'll need some means of synchronization between the processes. Perhaps that synchronization "thing" (shared mutex?) includes a memory barrier? Having to declare the whole buffer as volatile sounds a bit drastic.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not "cozy" with this idea – not at all.  Timing problems could abound.

Comment: Even for a 1 byte semaphore I need the modified value to be instantly available to the child process. As I said the child process is very limited (runs inside an emulator).

Comment: I suspect that the answer will be quite different for each OS, so perhaps you can restrict it to just one OS? Then later ask several questions if needed.

Answer (score 1):

`WriteProcessMemory` will happily do exactly what it's told. It writes to memory, and the CPU cache(s) will end up in a logically valid (but unspecified) state afterwards.

However, be aware that the other program is not made aware of those writes. And if it has its own idea of caching, including such mechanisms as caching variable values in registers, then those copies will NOT be updated. There is no way in which the OS can know how each language implements such caching mechanisms, but performance concerns dictate that most serious programming languages have mechanisms like this.

If the written-to program uses C or C++ `volatile` pointers, this is partially mitigated. The compiler cannot eliminate the reads entirely. However, such reads can be reordered with other instructions as long as those are not *observable*. That might affect their timing, which gives an effect similar to caching - your `WriteProcessMemory` might be too late.

Comment: So if I access shared data via volatile pointers and add memory barriers I'm somewhat on the safe side? Ignoring that semaphores need to be read / written atomically.

Comment: @HenrikS: If you have that level of control, build a proper IPC channel. Hoping that the compiler does exactly what you think it might do is not a solid basis for software engineering.